# Dynamically TextView Or buttons Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, button, textview

I'm not sure how to do this:

I have a variable that is passed threw an intent to my new activity.
This variable is a Number. That number received threw the intent will be different depending on the user.

So I want to dynamically write buttons or texViews depending on Number variable.

Example : Number = 4;
There is 4 buttons or textviews (with onclick listener each and text written has Button 1, Button 2, et. ).
Example Number = 10;
There is 10 buttons or textviews or etc. (with onclick listeners each).

Not sure how I can approach this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can create new dynamic views something like that:

```java
    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setText("Push Me");
    
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourLinearLayoutId);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    
    // with addView method you say to your app when you want to add this view inside on your LinearLayout view
    ll.addView(myButton, lp);
```